# Connect QMenu::addAction directly to lambda (function signature mismatch)

Tags: c++, qt

How can I connect a `QAction` directly with lambda slot?

```
QMenu m;
```

Working:

```
QAction newSubfolder(QIcon(":/icons/newfolder.png"),tr("New Subfolder"),&m);
m.addAction(&newSubfolder);
connect(&newSubfolder,&QAction::triggered,
        this,[this,p](){qDebug()<<"New Subfolder";});
```

Not working:

```
m.addAction(QIcon(":/icons/newfolder.png"),tr("New Subfolder"),
                [this,p](){qDebug()<<"New Subfolder";});
```

Error:

```
No matching function for call to 'QMenu::addAction(QIcon, QString, FolderMenuWidget::showContextMenu(QPoint)::__lambda0)'
                 [this,p](){qDebug()<<"New Subfolder";});
                                                       ^
```

Yes I see the error message but I don't understand what I need to change for the lambda slot. It also does not work if I add the member pointer `this` before the lambda.

This is in Qt 5.3.

Comment: It doesn't look like `QMenu::addAction` has an overload that takes a lambda.

Comment: There is an AddAction that takes a functor.  Maybe it checks the signature in which case try this:  `[this,p](bool){qDebug()<<"New Subfolder";}`

Comment: Looking closer, the functor overrides are new in Qt 5.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `addAction` overload you're looking for has been added in Qt 5.6.